# android emulator for animations and more complex application

Tags: android, emulation

I've already installed every requirements for android development.

**Question:**

Is there an emulator that best works for animation and dynamic data?

I know the emulator of the sdk package still works for this but too slow for animations..

I've searched around but still talking about just the same emulator.

Comment: AFAIK there are no emulator besides the emulators from the SDK. You could try giving the emulator more RAM... but Android emulator is still slow, yes, maybe get a test device?

Comment: yes..adding more ram on it works still the same.. Yes too, I do have a test device..Im just curious if there is a 3rd party emulator that works for this type of dev rather than installing all over again to my device .. thanks,

Comment: there are emulators besides the ones from SDK, try [buildroid](http://www.buildroid.org), i would say it's faster than the SDKs.

Comment: Test device approach is not that bad (after you get used to it ;) ). You just connect the device with USB to the computer, and if using eclipse you just have to run and it starts the app automatically on the device... you don't need to install manually.